# Redirecionamento com htaccess mantendo a URL

Tags: php, htaccess

Preciso redirecionar um domínio registrado (dominio.com.br) para uma pasta do domínio da minha hospedagem (dominio.com/exclusive), porém quero manter o dominio.com.br na barra de endereço, sem perder a integridade da URL, ou seja, todas as páginas também fique na barra de endereço ex: dominio.com.br/contato, /servico, /institucional....

É possível fazer essa regra no htacess?
Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: não poderia resolver isso no virtualhost?

Answer (score 3):

Escreva seu `.htaccess` assim

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^$ exclusive/index.php [L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ exclusive/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Caso queira implementar URL amigáveis:

[Implementando URL amigáveis com roteamento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/95310/url-amigavel-dinamica/98403?noredirect=1#comment200509_98403)

Comment: Cara, estava a uns 3 dias tentando resolver isso. Valeu!

Comment: Opa! Que bom! As ordens 

Comment: Posso te fazer uma pergunta? Isso é um redirecionamento ou uma inclusao? Tipo.. ele inclui o diretorio ou redireciona o usuario ao diretorio? Só por curiosidade..

Comment: Ao acessar, ao invés de usar a pasta primária, a chamada vai para outra pasta. É um tipo de redirecionamento, mas sem devolver isso para o cliente. É uma ação interna apenas. Por exemplo, ao usar o exemplo acima, uma URL apenas com o domínio vai chamar o “exclusiva/índex.php” sobrescrevendo a índex da pasta raiz. Outra URL qualquer vai usar a pasta “exclusive” como a pasta raiz.

Comment: Entendi.. Obrigado mais uma vez.

Answer (score -3):

É possível fazer por .htaccess sim, porém eu recomendo uma maneira mais fácil e eficiente utilizando a propiedade de JavaScript(window.location.href) fazendo com que você possa personalizar colocando tempo e etc... ao seu gosto.

**Exemplo da propiedade window.location.href**
`window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com.br/'; // Redireciona você para o site da Google`

Comment: Na verdade o window.location somente redireciona para determinado endereço, isso não solucionaria o meu problema.