# url amigavel dinamica

Tags: php, htaccess

como faco para minha `url` que e assim: `detalhe.php?cat=1` ficar tipo assim detalhe/televisão
meu `.htaccess` :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  index.php?url=$1 [QSA] [L]
```

e meu index que faz a ligação para as paginas:

```
$url = (isset($_GET['url'])) ? $_GET['url'] : 'home';
$url = array_filter( explode('/', $url));

$file = $url[0].'.php';
if(is_file($file))
    include $file;
else
    include '404.php';
```

como posso fazer isto com o meu código?

Comment: Eu não acho que você consiga, só pelo .htaccess, alterar algo de acordo com um banco de dados. Provavelmente você vai ter que alterar no Javascript direto e usar o .htaccess para passar como parâmetro (apenas para não dar erro de página quando o usuário acessar /televisao)

Comment: Cara você está na direção certa, onde você empacou exatamente? a segunda parte do array você tem que passar como parâmetro para seu arquivo do include. A visão correta sobre o problema seria a url detalhe/televisao se torna ?url=detalhe/televisao dai em diante você monta rotas baseadas em padrões.

Comment: Recomendo você usar algum router para fazer a interpretação das urls. Mais fácil do que implementar um próprio. 
Por exemplo o Klein - https://github.com/chriso/klein.php

Answer (score 1):

Pelo seu código você deve estar com problemas ao criar rotas e passar os parâmetros via `GET`. Como não está usando orientação a objeto, as coisas ficam um pouco mais chatas de fazer, e chamar arquivos direto pode ser um grande erro de segurança, apesar de verificar se é um arquivo válido.

O `.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^$ index.php?url=$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

O arquivo `index.php`

```
if (isset($_GET['url']) === false) {
    include '400.php';
    exit();
}

$url = $_GET['url'];
$routes = array(
    '' => array(
        'file' => 'principal',
        'params' => array()
    ),
    'detalhe/televisao' => array(
        'file' => 'detalhe',
        'params' => array('cat' => 1)
    )
);
if (isset($routes[$url])) {
    $actualRoute = $routes[$url];
    $file = __dir__ . DR . $actualRoute['file'] . '.php';

    if (file_exists($file)) {
        foreach ($actualRoute['params'] as $name => $value) {
            $_GET[$name] = $value;
        }
        include $file;
    } else {
        include '501.php';
    }
} else {
    include '404.php';
}
```

O exemplo acima torna necessário que todas as URLs sejam conhecidas, sendo assim vamos modificar o código para que possamos usar palavras chaves com a intenção de identificar determinados trechos da url requisitada.

Iremos definir duas palavras chaves `:controller` e `:params` que indicarão respectivamente o arquivo que será carregado e os parâmetros que serão passados.

Por exemplo:

- Criamos uma rota `:controller/:params`
- A URL recebida é `detalhe/televisao/lcd/lg`

  - `:controller` receberá o valor `detalhe`
  - `:params` receberá o valor `televisao/lcd/lg`.

Alterando nosso código ficará assim:

```
define('DR', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

// Caso o htaccess não tenha passado a variável `url`, redireiona para
// o erro 404.
if (isset($_GET['url']) === false) {
    include '400.php';
    exit();
}

// Obetm o caminho desejado e trata retirando a barra no final e barras
// duplicadas.
$url = $_GET['url'];
if ( substr( $url, -1 ) == '/' ) {
    $url = substr( $url, 0, -1 );
}
$url        = str_replace( '//', '/', $url);

// Define as rotas aceitas pelo sistema.
// Uma rota pode ser definida com um valor exato do caminho ou usar as palavras
// chaves abaixo:
//
//   :controller   que define o nome do arquivo que será chamado e
//   :params       que define os parâmetors que serão passados para o arquivo.
$routes = array(
    '' => array(
        'file' => 'principal',
        'params' => array()
    ),
    'detalhe/televisao' => array(
        'file' => 'detalhe',
        'params' => array('cat' => 1)
    ),
    'detalhe/:params' => array(
        'file' => 'detalhe',
        'params' => array('cat', 'artigo')
    )
);

// Define quais são as palavras chaves
$keywords = array(
    '/',
    ':controller',
    ':params'
);

// Define a expressão regular para cada palavra chave.
$keywordsPattern = array(
    // Apenas para escapar as barras na expressão regular
    '\/',

    // Aceita letras de "a" a "z" e os simbolos "_" e "-"
    '(?P<controller>[\w_\-]+)',

    // Obtem tudo a partir de quando for achado a palavra chave ":params"
    // Exemplo:
    //   Url = detalhe/televisao/1
    //   Rota = 'detalhe/:params'
    //   Parametros encontrados: 'televisao/1'
    '(?P<params>.+)'
);

// Inicia a variável que irá armazenar os valores das palavras chaves
// encontradas.
$matches = array();

// Percorre todas as rotas
foreach ($routes as $route => $config) {
    // Troca as palavras chaves por suas respectivas expressões regulares.
    // Exemplo:
    //   Rota: 'detalhe/:params'
    //   Regex: /^detalhe\/(?P<params>.+)\/?$/i
    $map = '/^' . str_replace($keywords, $keywordsPattern, $route) . '\/?$/i';

    // Verifica se a url requisitada atende a expressão regular da rota.
    if( preg_match( $map, $url, $matches ) === 1) {
        // Se foi atendida define a rota atual.
        $actualRoute = $config;

        // Verifica se foi encontrada a palavra chave :controller e define o
        // o nome do arquivo.
        if (isset($matches['controller'])) {
            $actualRoute['file'] = $matches['controller'];
        }

        // Verifica se foi encontrada a palavra chave :params
        if (isset($matches['params'])) {
            // Separa a string encontrada como por exemplo 'televisao/1' pelas
            // barras e define os valores dos parâmetros.
            // Por exemplo, se nas rotas foi definido
            //   'params' => array('cat', 'artigo')
            // então
            //   'cat' = televisao
            //   'artigo' = 1
            $params = explode('/', $matches['params']);
            foreach ($actualRoute['params'] as $key => $param) {
                $actualRoute['params'][$param] = isset($params[$key]) ? $params[$key] : null;
                unset($actualRoute['params'][$key]);
            }
        }
        // Se a rota foi encontrada, para de percorrer as rotas.
        break;
    }
}

// Se não foi encontrada nenhuma rota ainda, verifica se a url requisitada
// atende alguma de forma direta. Um exemplo no nosso caso seria a rota
// 'detalhe/televisao'.
if ($actualRoute !== false && isset($routes[$url])) {
    $actualRoute = $routes[$url];
}

// Faz a inclusão dos arquivos.
if ($actualRoute) {
    $file = __dir__ . DR . $actualRoute['file'] . '.php';

    if (file_exists($file)) {
        foreach ($actualRoute['params'] as $name => $value) {
            $_GET[$name] = $value;
        }
        include $file;
    } else {
        include '501.php';
    }
} else {
    include '404.php';
}
```

Essa é uma implementação adaptada dos recursos de roteamento de frameworks como CakePHP, Symfony, Laravel, etc. Como esses frameworks chamam métodos, e aqui só passamos os parâmetros para a váriavel global `$_GET` é muito importante valida-los e tomar sempre o cuidado de manter a mesma ordem da defina no array de rotas.

O que define os nomes das variavels como `$_GET['cat']` é o array `params` da rota, sendo assim é muito importante que seja definido em todas as rotas. Nas frameworks isso não é necessário pq as váriaveis são os parâmetros dos métodos, por exemplo:

```
public function detalhe($categoria, $artigo = null) {
}
```

onde o parâmetro `$categoria` é obrigatório e `$artigo` não.

Lembre-se que os arquivos de erro é muito importante passar o cabeçalho informando que se trata de um erro.

```
header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 400 Bad Request', true, 400);
header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 404 Not Found', true, 404);
header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 500 Internal Server Error', true, 500);
header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 501 Not Implemented', true, 501);
```

Comment: cara voce poderia me explicar a parte do $routes =array por que tipo isso nao iria receber dinamicamente o valor. pelo o que eu intendi eu terei q preencher o array manualmente e sempre saber o id que entrara estou certo sobre isso?

Comment: Sim está certo, porém vc pode criar essas rotas buscando do banco de dados o valor preparado para url e montar as rotas. Por exemplo na tabela categoria vc tem "carros esportivos" em um campo já tem o valor preparado "carros-esportivo" e vc monta sua url. Existe a possibilidade tb de adicionar palavras chaves nas rotas como :controller, :action, :params. Mas aí teria que usar expressão regular. Se precisar posso editar a resposta com a implementação disto

Comment: cara sinceramente fiquei perdido to tentando intender isso agora se vc puder dar um edit pra mim tentar visualizar de forma diferente

Comment: A lógica pelo que me parece você entendeu, no caso eu fiz uma implementação onde vc deverá conhecer todas as Urls.  Como quer algo mais flexível, quando eu chegar em casa adiciono a possibilidade de usar palavras chaves

Comment: sim obg a logica ta de boa o que ta me confundido e isso msm de usar as palavras chaves e deixar mais dinamico