# Redirecionar uma url virtual

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Como faço para redirecionar uma url do meu website numa subpasta.

Exemplo:

Banco de dados:

`ID | ENDEREÇO              | ESCREVER NO INDEX.PHP
1   | example.com/extranet  | <span>Sou o extranet</span>
2   | example.com/topico1   | <span>Sou o topico1</span>`

No caso o que eu quero e que o usuario acesse a URL sem precisar criar varias pastas no servidor com um index nelas. assim tornando a navegaçao mais simples.

Eu pensei num array, mas não sei como funciona muito isso de redirecionamento.

> *OBS: Esta é uma technica se não me engano 000webhost.com usa no ZyroWebSiteBuilder.*

Um array por exemplo:

```php
$pages = array(
        '0' => array('id' => '1', 'alias' => 'extranet', 'file' => '1.php'),
        '1' => array('id' => '2', 'alias' => 'topico1', 'file' => '2.php'),
        '2' => array('id' => '3', 'alias' => 'topico2', 'file' => '3.php')
    );
```

E no caso depois desse array ele executa `include('$pages[NUMERO]');`

Comment: É confuso discernir o quê responder. Não sei ao certo se apenas quer redirecionar de X para Y ou se é viável explicar sobre MVC ou roteamento. Se puder reformular a pergunta, talvez ajude-nos a entender.

Comment: editei a resposta!

Comment: Editou a pergunta você quis dizer né?

Comment: desculpa, sim! : )

Comment: Veja essa pergunta aqui, pode resolver seu problema http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/95310/3938

Comment: sim, nessa pergunta esta muito complexa! eu quero uma coisa mais resumida.

Comment: Se eu entendi direito, URL amigável deve servir para você, não?

Comment: Então coloque essa reposta por favor para eu aprovar, mas tem um problema, como eu defino a lista "`array`" de URL?

Comment: O primeiro código postado na resposta que dei lá é exatamente o que quer, a única alteração que talvez precise é montar a váriavel `$routes` de lá com informações do banco. Mas pense que em toda a requisição que fizer, vai ter essas buscas no banco